# Does for a given graph G, both DSF and BFS will be same only when the graph is not cyclic in nature?

Tags: algorithm

Does for a given graph G, both depth first search and breadth first search will be same only when the graph is not cyclic in nature ??

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to explain and visualize in terms of a rooted tree.

In the case of BFS, we will visit the tree 'level-by-level'. All nodes of a level will be printed before the next level is visited.

In the case of DFS, we will go through all levels of a node to the leaf before we visit the next. So it's more of a 'strand-by-strand' traversal.

If you visualize the two, it is clear that BFS and DFS traversal are identical when the graph is such that each node has one incoming and outgoing edge, except for the end nodes which have one edge. Hence, the graph should be of the form A_4->A_3->A_4..->A_N. Basically, there is exactly one strand of DFS here.

The other possibility is a star-configuration, i.e., one root whose children are all leaves. There the strand-by-strand and level-by-level approaches are identical. Basically there is one level of BFS here.

I doubt there will be a case where there are both multiple levels of BFS and multiple strands of DFS where the identical traversal will hold.

And in either of these cases, the graphic is not cyclic. So we can conclude (not a rigorous proof) that if the BFS and DFS traversals are identical, the graph is acyclic.

Note that there are a number of graphs (any tree which does not fit into the above patterns) different from the above cases where the DFS and BFS traversals are different. Hence the converse of the statement is not true.